# Is there any way to import Shader animations to unity.?

Tags: animation, materials, unity

I am building a glowing platform for my 3D game. I used Cycles' Emission node mixed to the Diffuse node to create a glowing effect with keyframes on the Mix Shader's factor to animate the glow intensity through time.

The effect works perfectly in Blender, but not in Unity.

Here is the image of my material nodes:
[image: demo picture]

Comment: Render out an animation of your effect, then stick it on a plane in unity.

Comment: I am sorry, as a beginner in blender its hard for me to understand your direct answer. Some details will be appreciated.

Comment: I am sorry it took a while but I understood your answer, I tried, first I inserted a key at fac 0 and after 6 frames at fac 1 inserted another key then again at frame 12 i inserted key at fac 0: then imported fbx file to unity, creates an animator , then created new state, loaded that particular glowing animation of 13 frames but it didn't worked.

Answer (score 0):

You can't directly export blender materials to unity. The standard shader in Unity features an emission slot though, which will accept a glow map (or simply just a color).

[image]

Comment: Thanks buddy for your help, now I am looking for how to create glow map.